# A RKHS interpretation of the Rydberg formula for hydrogen and an application for physics?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, matrices, hilbert-spaces, physics

I was thinking if it is possible to define an inner product between two small physical objects with a positive definite kernel and was led to look at the Rydberg formula:

[The Rydberg formula for hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula#For_hydrogen) is written in Wikipedia as $n_2 > n_1$:

$$\frac{1}{\lambda_{\mathrm{vac}}} = R_\text{H}\left(\frac{1}{n_1^2}-\frac{1}{n_2^2}\right)$$

This might be rewritten as (for any natural numbers $n_1,n_2$):
$$\frac{1}{R_\text{H}\lambda_{\mathrm{vac}}} = \sqrt{\left | \frac{1}{n_1^2}-\frac{1}{n_2^2} \right |}^2 = \sqrt{\left ( \min(\frac{1}{n_1},\frac{1}{n_1})^2+\min(\frac{1}{n_2},\frac{1}{n_2})^2 -2\min(\frac{1}{n_1},\frac{1}{n_2})^2\right )}^2 = d(n_1,n_2)^2$$

or equivalently:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{R_\text{H} \lambda_{\mathrm{vac}}}} = d(n_1,n_2)$$

where we have set:

$$k(a,b) = \min(1/a^2,1/b^2) = \min(1/a,1/b)^2 = 1/\max(a,b)^2$$

which is a positive definite kernel on the natural numbers.

and $d(a,b) = \sqrt{k(a,a)+k(b,b)-2k(a,b)}$ is the distance measured between the two natural numbers in the Hilbert space.

Q1) [Looking at the Gram matrix](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxljr0OgkAQhHsS3uGCzR5eUIyViZ2R3tYYc8qCF2CPLKcSn15-1BidcubbnUkxE0UBWp3kyvdEJ0Z3ZRLxrNLt4Ifhwvd8L-3IJAH64Srt2LSw37--iMyy0MKQYE05QqxoGsvDYJ_-bMWG8vVus5V9he_1FH1T8XL-Lqw71gGpYURElisIFoGUYzoZ4zEsMXNHNDnSDc_OcgMfrDSEUJrGwcPU8D1GNZYdpq8X47Uur9gfd4qai72DfALdmVdH&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) $G_n = (k(a,b))_{1 \le a,b \le n}$ can it be proved or disproved if the Gramian matrix has a converging spectral norm:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |G_n|_2 \approx 1.110288561$$

Output of the Sagemath script:

```
1 1.0
2 1.0756939094329987
3 1.095314794377045
4 1.1025233075784278
5 1.1057634181208507

70 1.1102858222735263
71 1.1102859354083545
72 1.1102860424258174
73 1.1102861437338427
74 1.110286239708146
75 1.1102863306951618
```

Q2) What is, if any, the physics interpretation of this?

The trace of $G_n$ converges to $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, because:

$$\operatorname{tr}(G_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n k(i,i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\max(i,i)^2} =  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} $$

So for $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

One possible application for physics (Q3 ?) is the following formula:

$$\pi = \arccos \left ( \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{xy}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{yz}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{xz}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{xy} \lambda_{yz}}}}\right ) +\arccos \left ( \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{zx}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{xy}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{zy}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{zx} \lambda_{xy}}}}\right ) +\arccos \left ( \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{yz}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{zx}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{yx}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{yz} \lambda_{zx}}}} \right ) $$

Every $3$ point metric space can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a triangle, (See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393140/whats-the-name-of-this-surface-a2b2c22abc-1-0 ), and hence for each triple of distinct natural numbers $x,y,z$ we get a triangle.

For three points $x,y,z$ in a metric space, we can define (using the law of cosines) the following quantity:

$$S(x,y,z) = \frac{d(x,y)^2+d(y,z)^2-d(x,z)^2}{2d(x,y)d(y,z)}$$

We then have:

$$\pi = \arccos(S(x,y,z))+\arccos(S(z,x,y))+\arccos(S(y,z,x))$$

In the case of the Rydberg formula, it follows with $\frac{1}{\lambda_{ab} R_H} = d(a,b)^2$
and

$$S(x,y,z) = \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{xy}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{yz}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{xz}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{xy} \lambda{yz}}}}$$

that:

$$\pi = \arccos \left ( \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{xy}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{yz}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{xz}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{xy} \lambda_{yz}}}}\right ) +\arccos \left ( \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{zx}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{xy}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{zy}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{zx} \lambda_{xy}}}}\right ) +\arccos \left ( \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{yz}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{zx}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{yx}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{yz} \lambda_{zx}}}} \right ) $$

where $\lambda_{ab}$ is the wavelength defined by the Rydberg formula:

$$1/\lambda_{ab} = R_H |1/a^2-1/b^2|$$

and $x,y,z$ are natural numbers.

A further possible application to physics might be given as described in the answer to this question:
[Simplex invariants?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396276/simplex-invariants)

```
n= 2
S  = range(1, 2)
Vector =  (-1.00000000000000)
Vardet: 0 = $ -c_{12}^{2} + 1 $
det =  0.000000000000000
n= 3
S  = range(1, 3)
Vector =  (-0.800000000000000, -0.316227766016838, -0.316227766016838)
Vardet: 0 = $ 2 \, c_{12} c_{13} c_{23} - c_{12}^{2} - c_{13}^{2} - c_{23}^{2} + 1 $
det =  1.94289029309402e-16
n= 4
S  = range(1, 4)
Vector =  (-0.611130643138949, 0.248069469178417, -0.509802390301733, -0.860054653873699, 0.250892341323851, -0.375447149783241)
Vardet: 0 = $ c_{14}^{2} c_{23}^{2} - 2 \, c_{13} c_{14} c_{23} c_{24} + c_{13}^{2} c_{24}^{2} - 2 \, c_{12} c_{14} c_{23} c_{34} - 2 \, c_{12} c_{13} c_{24} c_{34} + c_{12}^{2} c_{34}^{2} + 2 \, c_{12} c_{13} c_{23} + 2 \, c_{12} c_{14} c_{24} + 2 \, c_{13} c_{14} c_{34} + 2 \, c_{23} c_{24} c_{34} - c_{12}^{2} - c_{13}^{2} - c_{14}^{2} - c_{23}^{2} - c_{24}^{2} - c_{34}^{2} + 1 $
det =  0.000000000000000
```

Here $n$ counts the number of distinct principal quantum number of an energy level and $\det=0$ gives as in the answer above an algebraic variety which should be satisfied by the $\lambda_{ij}$.

Example for $n=3$ we get [the Cayley nodal cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_nodal_cubic_surface) which is studied in algebraic geometry:

$$0 = 2 \, c_{12} c_{13} c_{23} - c_{12}^{2} - c_{13}^{2} - c_{23}^{2} + 1 $$

where $c_{12} = S(x,y,z), c_{13} = S(z,x,y), c_{23} =  S(y,z,x)$

Here is a picture of it:

[image: cayley_nodal_cubic]

Example for $n=4$ the algebraic variety is given by:

$0=c_{14}^{2} c_{23}^{2} - 2 \, c_{13} c_{14} c_{23} c_{24} + c_{13}^{2} c_{24}^{2} - 2 \, c_{12} c_{14} c_{23} c_{34} - 2 \, c_{12} c_{13} c_{24} c_{34} + c_{12}^{2} c_{34}^{2} + 2 \, c_{12} c_{13} c_{23} + 2 \, c_{12} c_{14} c_{24} + 2 \, c_{13} c_{14} c_{34} + 2 \, c_{23} c_{24} c_{34} - c_{12}^{2} - c_{13}^{2} - c_{14}^{2} - c_{23}^{2} - c_{24}^{2} - c_{34}^{2} + 1 $

Let $\phi(a) = \frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{i=1}^a \sqrt{2i-1}e_i$ be an embedding of the natural number $a$ into the Hilbert space $l_2$ ( We might call this one feature vector of the natural number $a$).

Then it follows that:

$$\left < \phi(a),\phi(b) \right > = \frac{1}{a^2b^2} \sum_{i=1}^{\min(a,b)} (2i-1) = \frac{\min(a,b)^2}{a^2b^2}= \frac{\min(a,b)^2}{\min(a,b)^2\max(a,b)^2}=  \frac{1}{\max(a,b)^2} = k(a,b)$$

The Lyman series and similarily the other following series might be visualized as:

[image: visualization_lyman_series]

[image: visualization_balmer_series]

In this visualization we use the fact that:

$$d(a,b)^2 + \frac{1}{a^2} = \frac{1}{b^2},\text{ if } b < a$$

which can be immediately recognized as Pythagoras theorem, since $|\phi(a)| = \frac{1}{a}$.
One can also recognize the circle of Thales in this context of visualization.
The angle $\rho$ between $n=a$ and $n=b$ used in this visualizations, is given by:

$$\cos(\rho) = \frac{k(a,b)}{\sqrt{k(a,a)k(b,b)}} = \frac{\frac{1}{\max(a,b)^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2b^2}}} = \frac{ab}{\max(a,b)^2} = \frac{\min(a,b)}{\max(a,b)}=\text{ one Jaccard kernel / similarity}$$

One can add, that doing kernel PCA with the given kernel $k(a,b)$ above, in two dimension, yields a similar, if not to say identical image
as used in the visualizations above.

**Edit with speculative hypothesis based on mathematical properties of the Rydberg formula**:

Physics interpretation:
The Rydberg formula:

$$1/\lambda_{ab} = R_H |1/a^2-1/b^2|, a \neq b , a,b \in \mathbb{N}$$

is symmetric in $a,b$. This suggests that it is possible to interchange $a$ for $b$ and vice versa in the hydrogen atom.
This change is accompained by an absorption or emission of light of wavelength $\lambda_{ab}$.

Hypothesis:

H0) The hydrogen atom might be thought of as a Hilbert space $H$ where the natural numbers are embedded with $\phi$, so that $\left< \phi(a) , \phi(b) \right > = k(a,b) = \frac{1}{\max(a,b)^2}$.

H1) One can only physically measure the distance $d(a,b) = \sqrt{|1/a^2-1/b^2|}$ between two feature vectors $\phi(a),\phi(b)$ of natural numbers $a,b$ in the hydrogen atom.

H2) The hydrogen atom maintains a state $\phi(n_1),\phi(n_2),\cdots,$, which might be thought of as a permutation of the feature vectors of natural numbers $\phi(1),\phi(2),\phi(3),\cdots$.

H3) Every physical measurment of $d(a,b)$ swaps $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ in the state of the hydrogen atom.

H4) The feature vector $\phi(x)$ of a natural number $x$, cannot be measured.

Comment:
All these hypothesis stem from the Hilbert-space interpretation of the Rydberg formula.

Since it is observed that by the law of cosine, we can associate to each tupel $(x,y,z)$ of natural numbers, an angle $[x,y,z]$ in a triangle
spanned by the vectors $\phi(x),\phi(y),\phi(z)$, where $[x,y,z] := S(x,y,z) := \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda_{xy}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{yz}}-\frac{1}{\lambda_{xz}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda_{xy} \lambda{yz}}}}$ is the angle at $\phi(y)$.

We give those three angles names:

$$\alpha = [z,x,y], \beta = [x,y,z], \gamma = [y,z,x]$$

Now measuring the distance $d(x,y)$ in an experiment induces a swapping of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ with a transposition $\tau = (x,y)$, will give us for every other natural number $z$:

$$ \tau \cdot \alpha = 2 \pi - \beta$$
$$ \tau \cdot \beta = 2 \pi - \alpha$$
$$ \tau \cdot \gamma = 2 \pi - \gamma$$

Applying $\cos$ to the last equations we get:

$$\cos(\tau \cdot \alpha) = \cos(\beta),\cos( \tau \cdot \beta) = \cos(\alpha) , \cos( \tau \cdot \gamma) = \cos(\gamma) $$.
Hence one might say that measuring $d(x,y)$ swaps not only the $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ but also the cosines of the corresponding angles in the Hilbert space.

For instance let at time $t$ be $\pi_t$ the state of the hydrogen atom. Then we measure $d(x,y),d(y,z),d(x,z)$ so we get after three measurements the new state $\pi_{\hat{t}}$:

$$\pi_{\hat{t}} = (x,z,y) \cdot \pi_t = (x,z)(y,z)(x,y) \cdot \pi_t$$

If on the other hand we would have measured $d(x,y),d(x,z),d(y,z)$ we would have gotten the new state $\pi_{\hat{t}}$:

$$\pi_{\hat{t}} = (x,z) \cdot \pi_t = (y,z)(x,z)(x,y) \cdot \pi_t$$

which has the same effect on $\pi_t$ as just measuring $d(x,z)$ in one step.

[Possibly related question where it is thought about applications of p.d. kernel on natural numbers in physics and the space of Gram matrices is a Riemann manifold.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396643/is-there-any-physics-theory-which-is-similar-to-these-analogies)

Comment: What do you mean by an application to physics?

Comment: @JeffHarvey: I think that viewing each hydrogen like atom in the context of the Rydberg formula as a Hilbert space with an inner product k(a,b) = 1/max(a,b)^2 on the natural numbers / "principal quantum number of an energy level" could shed some surprising results in physics, because of the underlying geometry in the Hilbert space. The triangle / trigonometric application might for instance be further developed to simplex invariants as is being done in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396276/simplex-invariants I think that changing the perspective a little bit, could surprise.

Comment: The Rydberg formula is well-explained by the fact that the energy levels of the hydrogen atom (to first approximation) go as $1/n^2$. The emissions come from transitions between energy levels, giving the formula. It’s very very far from clear what need there is for additional formalism on top of this extremely straightforward explanation.

Comment: Dear @AaronBergman: The positive definite kernels on natural numbers seem to pop up in number theory at different places and even in music theory. I hoped for to find them also in physics, but did not know where to look for because of my limited physics knowledge. I was searching a formula with natural numbers in it, so it happened to be the Rydberg formula. As for your request: I do not have all answers. I thought that sharing this idea might or might not lead to something surprising, and so I wrote the question. In this formalism: (len. of vector)^2 =  energy level, dist.² ~ | diff. energy|

Comment: in reference to the hypotheses added to the post: I would think that $\phi(1)$ is the ionization potential of hydrogen, which is measurable (13.6 eV), so I don't think H4 holds.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I meant that $\phi(n)$ might have a different form / embedding distinct from $\phi(n) = 1/n^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{2i-1}e_i$, but we can not observe "its form" or which kind of embedding it is. This is known as: "RKHS might have different feature maps" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Feature_maps, so it does not make sense to pin to one specific feature map.

Comment: @AaronBergman: For H1?

Comment: I don’t want to be obnoxious here, but H1-H4 are all wrong. For H1, there isn’t an embedding of the natural numbers; the eigenspaces of the Hamiltonian have dimension > 1. For H2, I’m not sure what this means, but I can’t think of a way a state can be described as a permutation of natural numbers. For H3, measurements collapse the state into an eigenvector of the measurement operator. The Rydberg formula comes from transitions between states, not measurements.

Comment: For H4, the embedding doesn’t exist, but the states of the hydrogen atom can be explicitly written down (again to a first approximation ignoring interactions).

Comment: Also, the Rydberg formula is not symmetric. One sign describes emissions, while the other describes absorption. I don’t want to discourage you from looking for cool mathematical structure, but you need to understand the existing theory first to build on it.

Comment: @AaronBergman: Thanks for your input. For H1 the embedding is just a mathematical abstraction, so there is no point in saying "it is there" or "there isn't an embedding". Like saying "i = sqrt(-1)", does it exist? Also I think that you are confusing the usage of Hilbert space in the existing theory with what I am suggesting. H2: Keeps track of the swaps $(a,b)$ so to say in a state and hence it is a permutation of the natural numbers like for example: 3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,.....  After the swap (3,4) we get: 4,2,1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,...... etc. For H3: see the comment on the swaps.

Comment: @AaronBergman: For H4). As I said: It makes no point to insist on the existence of some mathematical structure if it shows up in a computation (like again i = sqrt(-1)). You could argue if it is _useful_. What I meant is this: There could be two distinct mathematical embeddings $\phi,\psi$ such that $<\phi(a),\phi(b) > = <\psi(a),\psi(b) > = k(a,b)$, and it makes it impossible to know by $H3$ which of the two is used.

Comment: @AaronBergman: But you are right, that one must learn existing physics, otherwise one gets stuck at mathematics, which I am learning very slow (physics) _if_ I have some time by reading Wikipedia articles.

Comment: @AaronBergman: The Rydberg formula is symmetric, if you insist that wavelengths are positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asks about a "physical interpretation", let me record the full expression for the wavelength $\lambda$ of the hydrogen spectral lines, which depends on four (not two) integers $n_1,n_2,j_1,j_2$,

$$\frac{1}{\lambda} = R_\text{H}\left(E_{n_1,j_1}-E_{n_2,j_2}\right)$$
$$E_{n,j} = -\frac{2}{\alpha^2}\left[ 1 - \left( 1 + \left[ \frac{\alpha}{n - j - \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\left( j + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 - \alpha^2}} \right]^2 \right)^{-1 / 2}\right].  $$
It so happens that $\alpha=0.00729735\cdots$ is small, and hence $E_{n,j}\approx 1/n^2$, but I don't think that any "inner product" interpretation can shed light on this formula.

A somewhat more promising line of approach to arrive at the spectral properties of atoms using purely mathematical reasoning (without physics input) is described in [Is there a good mathematical explanation for why orbital lengths in the periodic table are perfect squares doubled?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418554/is-there-a-good-mathematical-explanation-for-why-orbital-lengths-in-the-periodic)

Comment: Excuse my naive question: I have my physics education from high school and wikipedia: How does one derive this expression for $E_{n,j}$? Could there be other mathematical expressions which give rise to the same measured experimental values for $E$?

Comment: these are eigenvalues of a self-adjoint second order differential operator in $\mathbb{R}^3$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom

Comment: Thanks. So the Rydberg formula is an approximation or completely wrong? (Well, to defend my position: You could assume that a physicist exploring the idea in the question above, did not know about the self-adjoint second order differential operator, so given the Rydberg formula as an experimental evidence, one could assume that he or she would might want to follow this idea along to where it might lead). My point of view is, that experiments do not decide mathematical interpretation:  There might be many possible closed forms: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.375447149783241

Comment: Looking at the Rydberg formula is, in fact, one of the things that led to the invention of quantum mechanics. The derivation of the $1/n^2$ is a chapter in any intro quantum book. I'd recommend reading that before trying to make this come out of a RKHS or whatever.

Comment: @AaronBergman: The $\min(a,b)$ function on the real $>0$ numbers is known to be a positive definite kernel. The Moore Aronszajn theorem guarantees the existence of a RKHS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Moore%E2%80%93Aronszajn_theorem to this kernel. You only need to prove that $k(a,b) = 1/\max(a,b)^2$ is a positive definite kernel on the natural numbers to convince yourself about the Hilbert space (RKHS) in the background. If the Rydberg formula is accurate to some degree one could take the RKHS point of view.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: In light of your new edit: I am not trying to explain the Rydberg formula. I am just pointing to this: If the Rydberg formula is accurate, then one might take (with the help of the Moore Aronszajn theorem) the point of view of the RKHS.